# How to print the 2nd biggest number without using function and arrays

Tags: javascript, math

```js
let biggestNo;

for (let i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
  const a = prompt("enter a number");
  if (!a) {
    break;
  } else {
    biggestNo = Math.max(a);
  }
}
console.log(biggestNo);
```

How do I print 2nd biggest number using this approach without using functions and arrays

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. (What you have is maybe a start, but not more than that.) ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. *(not my downvote if any show up)*

Comment: You only have one number, there is no 2nd biggest number?

Comment: @GoldenretriverYT there is a loop there!

Comment: @Jamiec he doesn't want to use arrays, so the loop makes literally no sense as he has no way to store numbers (except he wants to create 10000 variables, which i doubt)

Comment: no, you'd only need 2 variables. the biggest and the second biggest. No arrays needed

Comment: I mean the current code doesnt work :D It would need to be `Math.max(a,biggestNo)` but thats besides the point!

Comment: @Jamiec oh yeah your right

Comment: @Jamiec I think you would need to record the third biggest or else you wont know if what you are reporting as the second biggest (out of the 10000 numbers someone is supposedly going to key in) is actually the lowest number you ever received as input

Comment: I'm still wondering why the OP cant use arrays (or, functions given theyve used 2 already)

Comment: Use a string then? Append each prompt answer to the string, separated by a control char, then use a regex to replace the highest number and again to find the 2nd highest. No array, no function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to match all numbers collected?

```js
let numbersString;

for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
  const a = prompt("enter a number");
  if (!a) {
    break;
  } else {
    numbersString += "-" + a
  }
}

const numbers = numbersString.match(/\d+/g)
const secondLargest = numbers[numbers.length - 2]

console.log(secondLargest);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with time complexity of `O(n)`:

```js
const array = [31, 25, 43, 19, 8, 42];

let main = -Infinity, sub = -Infinity;

for (let num of array) {
  if(num > main) {
    sub = main;
    main = num;
  } else if(num > sub) {
    sub = num;
  }
}

console.log('biggest: ' + main);
console.log('second biggest: ' + sub);
```

---

Using user input:

```js
let main = -Infinity, sub = -Infinity;

const total = 5;
for(let i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
  const num = +prompt(`Enter a number(${i} of ${total}):`)
  if(num > main) {
    sub = main;
    main = num;
  } else if(num > sub) {
    sub = num;
  }
}

console.log('biggest: ' + main);
console.log('second biggest: ' + sub);
```